# how to download this com.ibm.mqtt.IMqttClient.jar file? without paho libarary using in eclips

Tags: android, mqtt

```
import com.ibm.mqtt.IMqttClient; 
import com.ibm.mqtt.MqttClient;
import com.ibm.mqtt.MqttException; 
import com.ibm.mqtt.MqttNotConnectedException; 
import com.ibm.mqtt.MqttPersistence;
import com.ibm.mqtt.MqttPersistenceException;
import com.ibm.mqtt.MqttSimpleCallback;
```

But I don't have `com.ibm.mqtt.IMqttClient`  this library so how can I download this jar file from internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those classes are not part of the Paho MQTT client, the are part of the old [IBM IA92 Java MQTT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24006006) client.

You should not use these are they are out of date, you should use the [Paho Java client](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/). And given that you have tagged this with Android you should be using the [Paho Android service](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/) rather than trying to roll your own with the Java client.